# Golang fails to write header to tar package？

Tags: go, tar

code show as below

```
    fInfo, err := os.Stat(fp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    header, err := tar.FileInfoHeader(fInfo, "")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    header.Name = name
    if header.Format == tar.FormatUnknown {
        header.Format = tar.FormatGNU
    }

    err = this.writer.WriteHeader(header)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    f, err := os.Open(fp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(this.writer, f)
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
```

Reporting an error in the diverted code

```
this.writer.WriteHeader(header)
```

The error is as follows

```
archive/tar: missed writing 15251 bytes
```

I have tested many times, I don't know why this error occurs in this way.

It should be noted that the content I packaged is the content in the U disk.

Comment: What is `this.writer`? Please provide a minimal code sample that we can copy and compile ourselves.

Comment: The `this` keyword is an anti-pattern in go.  https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-names

Comment: I can't reproduce your error: https://go.dev/play/p/kz9J5c0xeh_b Please provide a more extended description

Answer (score 2):

As it is mentioned in the documentation, [WriteHeader](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.6:src/archive/tar/writer.go;l=67) implicitly calls [Flush](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.6:src/archive/tar/writer.go;l=50), which in turn [checks](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.6:src/archive/tar/writer.go;l=53) is there any [number of remaining bytes](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.6:src/archive/tar/writer.go;l=491) to write. If so it will [return an error](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.6:src/archive/tar/writer.go;l=54) that you got.

The number of remaining bytes is stored in `nb` variable and initialised when you write header first time. Then every time when you write some content it will be decreased by a number of bytes written.

If `nb` is more then zero and you try to call `WriteHeader` second time you will get this error.